# On fancybox open and close run functions

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there a way to run a function on Fancybox open and close?

I want to run a small function as the Fancybox trigger is fired, and when the Fancybox window is closed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fancybox has some callbacks for that so if running v1.3.4 you could do

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   "onComplete": function(){
      // fancybox is open, run myFunct()
   },
   "onClosed": function(){
      // fancybox is closed, run myOtherFunct()
   }
});
```

for v2.1.x

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   afterShow: function(){
      // fancybox is open, run myFunct()
   },
   afterClose: function(){
      // fancybox is closed, run myOtherFunct()
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you JFK. Exactly what I was after.

Comment: Just used it in 2.1.5 - works as expected!  Thanks :-)